# Filter with at least two rows with specific value in group id and have at least two different values for column a

Tags: r, dplyr

```r
dat <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4, 5, 5,6,6,6,7,7,7), 
                  a = c(1,2,2,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2, 1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1))
View(dat1)
```

##### Desired Output:

```
id a
2 1
2 1
2 2
3 1
3 1
3 1
3 2
3 2
3 2
4 1
4 1
4 1
4 1
4 2
```

I tried with the following code:

```r
library(dplyr)  
dat1 <-  dat %>%  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(n() > 2) %>% 
  filter(any(a!= 2)) %>% filter(any(a != 1)) %>%  filter(a == 1 | (cumsum(a == 2) == 1))
```

But the group id=1 must remove since have only one row with the **a==1** value. I need at least 2 rows with a==1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `n_distinct` to get count of unique values and `sum` to count the occurrence of `a = 1` for each `id`.

Using `dplyr`, you can do -

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(a) >=2  && sum(a == 1) >= 2) %>%
  ungroup

#      id     a
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     2     1
# 2     2     1
# 3     2     2
# 4     3     1
# 5     3     1
# 6     3     1
# 7     3     2
# 8     3     2
# 9     3     2
#10     4     1
#11     4     1
#12     4     1
#13     4     1
#14     4     2
```

This can also be written in base R and `data.table`.

```
#Base R
subset(dat, as.logical(ave(a, id, 
       FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)) >= 2 && sum(x == 1) >= 2)))

#data.table
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, .SD[uniqueN(a) >=2  && sum(a == 1) >= 2], id]
```